# Retrieve a Filtered Data extension with fields of both the data extension

Tags: dataextensions, relationships, filters

We are using Data Relationships as a Data Filter to retrieve data from two data extensions, but the filtered data extension has fields only that of the source data extension. What must I do so that I have fields of both the data extension in the filtered data extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a filtered data extension will only give you fields from the source data extension.

You have to create a standard data extension with the required fields you need in it.  Then, you have to use SQL Query activity (in automation studio) to capture/filter data from 2 data extensions and put in the standard data extension. Use SQL JOINS to fetch data from 2 different data extensions.